# Position a graphic within template cadernos de astronomia

Tags: graphics, positioning, includegraphics, renewcommand

I want to insert an image in the upper right corner of the first page of the document. I am using a template from [overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/cadernos-de-astronomia/qyfzpdxhspzd). I want the image next to the title, author and abstract. I visualised it in the picture below.

[image: Example of the position of the image]

I already tried to put the text in a box and wrap the graphic on the rights side but this didn't work. The problem is the custom made `\maketitlepage` which I don't fully understand:

```
\renewcommand*{\maketitle}{%
    \twocolumn[%
    \vspace{.3cm}%
    \begin{flushleft}%
        {\LARGE \fontfamily{bch} \fontshape{sl} \selectfont \@title \par }%
        \vskip 1.0em%
         \@author %
    \end{flushleft}%
    \hrulefill \par
    {\normalsize \bfseries Resumo \par}%
    {\small \selectfont \@resumo \par  }%
    \vskip .5em%
    {\normalsize \bfseries Abstract \par}%
    {\small \selectfont \@abstract \par  }%
    \vskip .5em%
    \hrule 
    \par
    \vskip 1em%
    {\small {\bfseries Palavras-chave:} \@pchave \par}%
    {\small {\bfseries Keywords:} \@keywords \par}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@doi}{nodoi}}{}{%
    \vskip 1em%
    {\small DOI: \href{http://doi.org/10.47456/Cad.Astro.v\@volume n\@numero.\@doi}{10.47456/Cad.Astro.v\@volume n\@numero.\@doi}}%
    }
    \vskip 2.5em]%
    \thispagestyle{capa}%
}
```